# Do Glassware Contacts created via Mirror API support GIFs

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Does anyone know off hand if contact (created via [Mirror API 1.1](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/contacts)) supported animated GIFs? The documentation recommends using a PNG but I was curious if other image formats were supported.

Answer (score 2):

They're supported for content URIs within HTML payloads per [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=101).

For example, attach a gif, `kitten-on-skateboard.gif` to your timeline item as an [attachment](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/timeline#inserting_a_timeline_item_with_media) and then use an html payload like this:

```
<article>
  <img src="attachment:0">
</article>
```

You can find further documentation on the [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#attachments).